# ng-pattern Vs script validation

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm validating date (Format is YYYY/MM/DD) using regular expression ng-pattern. When i use below code in UI, it's working fine.

```
<input type="text" class="k-fill" ng-pattern="/((^[1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1]{1}[0-2]{1})\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1,2]{1}\d{1}|[3]{1}[0,1]{1})$/" ng-model="Request.ExpDate" id="ExceptedDate" name="ExceptedDate" ng-readonly="true" required />
```

But i want to validate the pattern inside of a function for pop-up a validation message. For achieving it I used below code inside one of my js file.

```
 var str = Request.ExpDate;
        var x = '/((^[1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1]{1}[0-2]{1})\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1,2]{1}\d{1}|[3]{1}[0,1]{1})$/';
        var patt = new RegExp(x);
        var res = patt.test(str);
```

if *res* return false, I can show a message. But the problem is, it is returning false for every dates which are even in the right format.

May I know the reason for why the regexp is working fine with ng-pattern and why it is not working properly inside JS function?

Comment: Can't you just show the error message as {{form.ExceptedDate.$valid}}

Comment: Leave out the constructor and use the regular expression literal, removing the quotes.

Comment: Try by ,var x = /((^[1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1]{1}[0-2]{1})\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1,2]{1}\d{1}|[3]{1}[0,1]{1})$/; without quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your regex returns `false` all the time because you included regex delimiters in the pattern that you initialize with a constructor notation (`new RegExp(var)`).

You do not have to use a constructor and can initialize `RegExp` using a regular literal in the form of `/.../`:

```
var str = Request.ExpDate;
var patt = /((^[1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1]{1}[0-2]{1})\/([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1,2]{1}\d{1}|[3]{1}[0,1]{1})$/;
var res = patt.test(str);
```

However, it seems your regex has some issues in it, here is a fixed version:

```
/^((199\d)|([2-9]\d{3}))\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/
```

I removed `{1}` limiting quantifier since it is redundant, and removed `,` from inside the character classes `[1,2]` and `[0,1]` since the comma was treated as a literal, and could mess up the results. We can also further enhance by removing unnecessary groups or turning them to non-capturing, but those are already cosmetic changes.

See sample:

```js
var str = "2992/10/31";
var patt = /^((199\d)|([2-9]\d{3}))\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/;
var res = patt.test(str);
document.write(res);
```

Note that you could also make use of [`Date.Parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to validate the date more precisely.